# How do I hold a file open (locked) from a Windows command-line shell script?

Tags: windows, shell, locking

I have been reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518151/how-to-check-in-command-line-if-a-given-file-or-directory-is-locked-used-by-any) about **detecting a locked file**, and now I would like to implement it in my scripts, so I will need a way to programatically detect it in **Windows shell scripting**.
The accepted solution gives a way to hold a file open/locked:

```
    (
      >&2 pause
    ) >> test.txt
```

but this solution needs a *key pressing*.
I would like to create a **Windows shell script** similar, like this:

```
[Create and locking of c:\Temp\ProgramRunning.lck]
--------------- Rest of the Script ---------------
[Blah blah blah]
---------- End of the Main Body the Script ----------
[Unlocking and deletion of c:\Temp\ProgramRunning.lck]
```

So, when the scripts **finishes**, the lock file gets *deleted* (and unlocked, of course). If this script gets **stopped**, Ctrl+C, window closed, hanging of the system or whatever, the lockfile is not deleted, but is *unlocked*.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `call` combined with output redirection to hold a file open until the call returns:

```
call :main 3>myopenfile.txt
goto :eof

:main
rem do whatever here
goto :eof
```

If needed, you can write to the file from within the call like this:

```
>>&3 echo hi
```

Comment: An ellegant idea, @HarryJohnston. What is the meaning of that *"3"*?

Comment: The stream number: 0 is the input, 1 is standard output, 2 is standard error; 3 through 9 are available for the user.  (Note that these extra streams are a feature of cmd.exe and are not available to other applications.)

Comment: The `>>&3 echo hi` idea is great: very useful for things like time stamps. Thanks, @HarryJohnston.