# How to dump output of Sysninternals handle.exe to a text file?

Tags: scripting, console, handle, sysinternals

I want to see who locks a file, quickly.
So I created a CMD script that will run Handle, put its output in a file and then open that file in the default text editor.

```
prompt $
cls
handle > handle.txt
handle.txt
```

When I run the script a new console wnd is open, I see handle running in it, then it quickly closes. It generates a file called handle.txt, but it is empty. 
I tried to run handle.exe as admin, but still doesn't work.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Did you try running procmon to monitor cmd.exe activity? it may give you a hint.